# How do I change properties of buttons within button boxes in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, designer

I have been searching online to no avail. Does anyone know how to access a button in a button box (created using the "Dialog with Buttons Right" template)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Designer, select the `OK` or `Cancel` button.  Then open the property editor and scroll down to the [`QDialogButtonBox`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdialogbuttonbox.html) section.  You can then expand the `standardButtons` item to see the various buttons that are available.  Other properties, such as the [`centerButtons`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdialogbuttonbox.html#centerButtons-prop) property, are also available.

However, designer gives you very little control over the button box.

In code, you can do many other things, such as change the text that appears on the "standard buttons." From the [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdialogbuttonbox.html#details):

```
findButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Find"));
findButton->setDefault(true);

moreButton = new QPushButton(tr("&More"));
moreButton->setCheckable(true);
moreButton->setAutoDefault(false);

buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(Qt::Vertical);
buttonBox->addButton(findButton, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
buttonBox->addButton(moreButton, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
```

As long as you give the button box a name in designer, you can set these properties in code.

Comment: I'm guessing the code for the form is generated and stored in some file so I can go into that file and change the button properties that I need to?

Comment: @KalebPederson If I append the OK/Cancel button box, the internal buttons cannot be clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this answer for the Python community. I am using PySide and faced a similar problem. I have a QDialogButtonBox and I would like to have my own buttons instead of the default ones.

I am using PySide which is more or less the exact replica of the c++ code, so I believe other c++ developers can also get something from it.

Here how I would do that:

```
        my_ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("My Ok Button")
        my_cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("My Cancel Button")
        ok_cancel_button = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        ok_cancel_button.addButton(my_ok_button, QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.AcceptRole)
        ok_cancel_button.addButton(my_cancel_button, QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.RejectRole)
```

I would then insert my button box to my layout like ususal:

```
layout.addWidget(ok_cancel_button, 1, 1)
```

Now later in my code I can do anything with my button. Lets change its name:

```
my_ok_button.setText("Some Other Name")
```

So then things to note here is that:

- you must set the role of the buttons in the addButton() method if you
  want to use functionalities given by standard buttons. E.g. if you
  wish to do something like below, you need to have the button roles
  set.

  **ok_cancel_button.accepted.connect(self.ok_method_handler)
  ok_cancel_button.rejected.connect(self.close)**

[More information can be found here.](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QDialogButtonBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.setStandardButtons)